# How is Shane Patton able to just get on a plane and leave?

Tags: the-white-lotus

At the end of season 1 of *The White Lotus*,

> Shane has stabbed and killed Armond in his room.

Nevertheless, the next time we see Shane, he is

> apparently shaking hands with the police, who drive away and leave, with him

getting on a plane and flying back home.  Since this is apparently the same plane

> that Armond's body has been loaded onto,

the flight must happen within a day or two.  Additionally, since Rachel is getting on the same plane, it is presumably the flight they originally planned to return on, which fits with the start of the series' timeline one week earlier.

How does this happen?  As I understand it, Hawaii isn't a state with a stand-your-ground law, so Shane's actions should at least rise to manslaughter.  Can you just walk away from a manslaughter charge with a handshake?  Did something blip by that I missed?

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, he told the police:

> This insanely high maniac who was hiding in my room and had pooped in my suitcase came at me with a knife and I didn't mean to stab him but he did end up stabbed

And since Shane is a well off young man with no record (though everything about him screams "future domestic violence case" to me and we yelled "Leave!" at the screen wife more than once) and the other young hotel employees could confirm some of the earlier wild behaviours, the police presumably decided this was all a terrible accident, and you're-free-to-go-sir.

This also fits with the overall theme,

> The rich tourists can do as they like and it's the locals or the immigrant hotel staff who pay the price. The tourists, rather like the [Gatsby's](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/327461-they-were-careless-people-tom-and-daisy--they-smashed-up), don't even know what they have broken as they wander off to their next adventure.

Comment: If you think there's someone in your place you call the police, you don't pick up a weapon and go looking for them.  (At least that's what civilized people do, and especially if they don't live in a "stand your ground" state.)  And if you _do_ kill someone, even in a "stand your ground" state, the case still needs to be adjudicated.  Otherwise you can kill people with impunity just by inviting them over and lying to the cops about it.

Comment: Absolutely! But once the only other witness is dead, you can tell whatever story you like, can't you? And if you're the one who will be believed, as in my second spoiler, then...